# Can I make some values of an array unchangeable in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, solution

I am designing a console-based Sudoku. According to the game, you can change entries as you move along the board. I've used a 2d array to store the values but the problem here is that I cannot make some of the entries constant as in the sudoku game where some values on the board cannot be changed so the user must reach a solution following those entries. So my question is:

**- How can I make some of the entries constant here?**

I have attached the code below

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77

class Sudoku
{
    int wholeArray[9][9];
    int number;

public:
    void setArray(void);
    void displayArray(int& x, int& y);
    void readNumber(void);
    void setPositions(int& x, int& y);
    void changeEntry(int &x, int &y);
};

void setConsoleColor(int textColor, int bgColor) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), (textColor + (bgColor * 16)));
}

void Sudoku::setArray(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            wholeArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Sudoku::displayArray(int& x, int& y)
{
    setConsoleColor(11, 0);
    cout << "\t\b\b\b1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9\n";
    cout << "   -------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "  | ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (x == i && y == j)
                setConsoleColor(0, 11);
            cout << wholeArray[i][j];
            setConsoleColor(11, 0);
            cout << " ";

            if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0)
                cout << "| ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            cout << "   -------------------------\n";
    }
}

void Sudoku::readNumber(void)
{
    cout << "Enter number you want to enter (from 1-9): ";
    cin >> number;
}

void Sudoku::setPositions(int& x, int& y)
{
        char key = _getch();
        if (key == KEY_UP)
            x--;
        if (key == KEY_DOWN)
            x++;
        if (key == KEY_LEFT)
            y--;
        if (key == KEY_RIGHT)
            y++;

        if (x < 0)
            x = 8;
        else if (x > 8)
            x = 0;

        if (y < 0)
            y = 8;
        else if (y > 8)
            y = 0;

        if (key == 'x')
            exit(0);
        if (key == 'v')
            changeEntry(x, y);
        system("cls");
}

void Sudoku:: changeEntry(int& x, int& y)
{
    int entry;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter value:\t";
        cin >> entry;
    } while (entry < 1 || entry > 9);

    wholeArray[x][y] = entry;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, entry;

    Sudoku s1;
    s1.setArray();

    s1.displayArray(x, y);
    while (1)
    {
        s1.setPositions(x, y);
        s1.displayArray(x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no automatic way of achieving this. This is part of your program logic, not something that could be done on the language level. You could for example add another array of `bool` in which you mark whether the corresponding entry in `wholeArray` is supposed to be unchangebable. Then, before setting a new value check whether modification is allowed and report an error to the user if it isn't.

Comment: You wouldn't make the array entries constant (in C++ sense). You would simply reject user input which tries to change them. Maybe you mean this, actually, but sounds like you have these two things confused.

Comment: Another option would be to use negative numbers as constants. Just print the abs of them. Or, create a `struct` like `struct entry {int value; bool is_const; }`. And other ways. It's up to you to decide.

Comment: Assign and maintain a flag at runtime for each cell that indicates whether or not the value in that cell is changeable.  Set these flags when you initialize or load your game board with the _"given"_ cells marked as unchangeable and the empty or user-filled cells marked as changeable.  If the user attempts to make a change to a _given_ cell, you could disallow it and remind the user about why _given_ cells cannot be changed.

Comment: You could make an object which has an editable property.  It would also have the current value and the correct value.  It could also have a list of all valid values that it could take based on the rules of the game.  Then you would store an array of objects instead of raw numbers.  Might be overly complicated...

Answer (score 2):

> Can I make some values of an array unchangeable in c++?

You can make an entire array unchangeable by making it an array of const objects. You can make an array entirely changeable by making it an array of non-const objects. C++ arrays are homogeneous, so you cannot have mix of differently qualified types.

What you could have is an array of `std::variant<T, const T>`. Or, you could simply write a class that wraps the array that allows modification only through member functions. Those member functions can refuse to change elements that you deem to be unchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another array forbidden[9][9] and the position that you don't want the user to change mark them for example

```
forbidden[1][0] = 1;
forbidden[2][5] = 1;
forbidden[3][7] = 1;
```

and when you want to change the value of your original array check the forbidden array first

```
if (key == 'v' && forbidden[x][y] != 1)
    changeEntry(x, y);
```

Comment: You are defining three different arrays rather than modifying an already declared array.

Comment: @WaisKamal it's just an error, the logic is still valid